# DJANGO-choicefield not appearing in website

Tags: html, django, django-forms, django-templates

views.py

```
def remark_proof_api(request, room_id, bills_slug):
    submission_form = SubmissionForm()
    try:
        room = Room.objects.get(join_code=room_id)
        room_bills = bills.objects.get(room=room, slug=bills_slug)

        if request.method == "POST":
            data = json.loads(request.body.decode("utf-8"))

            submission_id = data.get("subId")
            status = data.get("status")

            if submission_id is not None and status in dict(Submission.STATUS_CHOICES).keys():
                sub = Submission.objects.get(id=int(submission_id))
                sub.status = status
                sub.save()

                return JsonResponse({"success": True})

    except (Room.DoesNotExist, bills.DoesNotExist, Submission.DoesNotExist, json.JSONDecodeError, ValueError) as e:
        return JsonResponse({"success": False, "error": str(e)})

    return JsonResponse({"success": False, "error": "Invalid request"})
```

models.py

```
class Submission(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bills = models.ForeignKey(bills, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    proof = models.FileField(null=True)
    STATUS_CHOICES = (('P', 'Pending'), ('A', 'Accepted'), ('R', 'Rejected'))

    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='P')
```

html

```
{% extends "base/room_home.html" %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" style="min-height: 100vh;">
    <div class="text-center">
        <h1>{{ room_bills.title }}</h1>
        <p>Due: {{ room_bills.due }}</p>

        <div class="col-3">
            <h3>Paid Members: </h3>
            <ul>
                {% for submission in submissions %}
                    <li>
                        <a href="proof/{{ submission.user.id }}" target="_blank">{{ submission.user.username }}</a>
                        {% if submission %}
                            <form class="statusForm" data-subid="{{ submission.id }}">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                {{ submission_form.as_p }}
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
                            </form>
                        {% endif %}
                    </li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            <h3>Did not pay members: </h3>
            <ul>
                {% for user in did_not_submit %}
                    <li>{{ user.username }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    document.querySelectorAll('.statusForm').forEach(form => {
        form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
            e.preventDefault();

            const data = {
                subId: form.getAttribute('data-subid'),
                status: form.querySelector('[name="status"]').value
            };

            let csrfToken = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content');

            fetch(`status`, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'X-CSRFToken': csrfToken
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(data)
            });

        });
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Submission

class SubmissionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Submission
        fields = ['proof', 'status']
```

my problem is my changing status is not appearing in my website, i dont know what is my problem

I tried manually typing the choices in my html and it appears but it doesnt change in my admin panel. I want when i change my status in html, it will also change in my admin panel

Comment: First, what is the JSON response you get when you try to change the status ?